# Google Sheets Trigger updates values in a table, but does not leave old values unchanged

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-macros

I have programmed a macro in Google Sheets that displays a table to show the history of certain data that changes every day. Every day the macro inserts a new line with a new date into the table. This is done using a trigger.
Problem: The trigger also changes the values (I don't mean the date, that works fine, I mean a value like 1,2,3,4,5,6) of the row created the day before. So every row contains the same data if the values change. However, I would like to display a history of the data.
So how can I prevent this?

Currently my evaluation list is the first sheet in this file, but if I move it to the 6th position and put a trigger on it, the values are still written on the 1st sheet, not on the evaluation list, but on the first sheet (but I want them on the 6th sheet). What do I have to enter into the code so that the values are entered on the 6th sheet (evaluation)?

Right now it looks like this:

```
function zeitStempelPerTriggerSetzen(){ 
  var tabellenblatt=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var aktuellerZeitpunkt=new Date(); 
  var zeitStempelFormat="dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss";
  tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+1,15).setValue(aktuellerZeitpunkt).setNumberFormat(zeitStempelFormat);   
  tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+0,16).setFormula('=\' checklist\'!BG8');
```

So for example row 1: `2019-10-16` value is 1 (this should stay 1, because i want to see the progress) But when I activate the trigger it makes a new row 2: `2019-10-17` value is now 2 but the value in row 1 gets changed to 2 too. And i want the value in row 1 to stay at 1.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Are you talking about the values in column 16? You populate this column with a formula, so if the value of all rows changes, this is because the content of `BG8` changes. How is this content generated?

Comment: yes the values in column 16 change, but I want them to stay untouched. So how do I solve this? In the moment I have 3 dates in my table and I dont want the values (column 16) of the dates (column 15) to change anymore, they should stay at value 1 when it was 1 at this day and don't change to value 2 for example when a new row with a new date gets added and the value change to 2 for the new date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to populate column 16 with the actual value in sheet `checklist`, cell `BG8` and you do not want the values of previous rows in column 16 to update when `BG8` updates - do not use formulas.

Instead modify

```
  tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+0,16).setFormula('=\' checklist\'!BG8');
```

to

```
  var checklist=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("checklist");
  var currentValue=checklist.getRange("BG8").getValue();
  tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+0,16).setValue(currentValue);
```

Comment: 1 moment I try this!

Comment: It says: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getActive(...).getSheetbyName is not a function

Comment: sorry, it is meant to be `getSheetByName` (capital B). Also make sure that "checklist" is spelled exactly the same way as the name of your sheet.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you are happy with my solution, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Currently my evaluation list is the first sheet in this file, but if I move it to the 6th position and put a trigger on it, the values are still written on the 1st sheet, not on the evaluation list, but on the first sheet (but I want them on the 6th sheet). What do I have to enter into the code in order to write the values on the 6th sheet (evaluation)?

Comment: u have an idea?

Comment: Instead of defining ` var tabellenblatt=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`, you can modify your code to ` var tabellenblatt=SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(name);` and specify the name of your evaluation sheet. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900660/creating-a-data-history-with-excel-vba-using-lastrow-time-stamp-and-workbook-sh could you please help me here? same problem but I basically need this in excel VBA now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your macro is assigning the value `=today()`, you can work around this by using the utility in app-scripts `var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy")`.

Comment: Can you post this in your Q?

Comment: So the problem is that the values come from another table and the values in this other table change from day to day. And when i activate the trigger it changes the old values, which i want to safe to see the progress/history of the values

Comment: Ah. Have you considered writing the new data to a new sheet? That should solve your difficulty.

Comment: Yes the data i reference to is in table checklist and I made a new table which name is Evaluation (there is my history/progress table) because I only want specific data in my history/progress table. But when a value in chchklist changes, it changes in my history table for all days that are already in my table, so the result is that I simply have no history... There are always the new data, just with different dates and that is the problem

Comment: Currently my evaluation list is the first sheet in this file, but if I move it to the 6th position and put a trigger on it, the values are still written on the 1st sheet, not on the evaluation list, but on the first sheet (but I want them on the 6th sheet). What do I have to enter into the code so that the values are entered on the 6th sheet (evaluation)?

Comment: Elaborate further in the Q @greenster10

Comment: I did, can you help me?

Comment: Sure! Gimme a day or so.