# Creating multiple data histories with Excel VBA using LastRow, Time Stamp and Workbook.sheetchange

Tags: excel, vba

I have programmed a manual macro in Excel VBA that displays 2 or in the future multiple tables to show the history of certain data in a sheet called "evaluation". The data i reference to is in the table "checklist".(Look below) The problem is that the data in "checklist" changes every day or more often. Every time the sheet changes the macro should insert a new row with a new date into the LastRow of the table in "evaluation".  I would like to display a history of the data in "evaluation". So the values in the row of the last change should stay stable. So for example row 1 in "evaluation": 2020-01-17 value is 1 (this should stay 1, because i want to see the progress) Now the sheet changes and row 2 gets inserted: row 2: 2020-01-18 value is now 2 (copied from checklist) and i want the value in row 1 to stay at 1 (because it was 1 before the last change).
 This part works perfectly with my 1st code: (see below), but if I want to record the data of the second table too (code 2) nothing happens... Do I have to just make an adjustment to my first code or how is it done? Right now it looks like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "checklist" Then
          'Monitoring from A3:E100, if different change this
          If Not Intersect(target, Range("A3:E3")) Is Nothing Then
             'if any monitoring here, please you add here
             Test target 'Here procedure to insert
          End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Test(target As Range)
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Range("evaluation!A" & Sheets("evaluation").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Range("evaluation!A1").Value <> "" Then
       LastRow = LastRow + 1
    End If
    'every change A3:E in checklist will insert row to this evaluation
    'but if different please you decide here
    Range("evaluation!A" & LastRow).Value = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm") 'you can change this
    Range("evaluation!B" & LastRow & ":F" & LastRow).Value = Range("checklist!A" & target.Row & ":E" & target.Row).Value
End Sub
```

the first codes are for the first table and the one below is for the second table:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange2(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "checklist" Then
          'Monitoring from A3:E100, if different change this
          If Not Intersect(target, Range("G3:K3")) Is Nothing Then
             'if any monitoring here, please you add here
             Test target 'Here procedure to insert
          End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Test2(target As Range)
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Range("evaluation!H" & Sheets("evaluation").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Range("evaluation!H1").Value <> "" Then
       LastRow = LastRow + 1
    End If
    'every change A3:E in checklist will insert row to this evaluation
    'but if different please you decide here
    Range("evaluation!H" & LastRow).Value = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm") 'you can change this
    Range("evaluation!I" & LastRow & ":M" & LastRow).Value = Range("checklist!G" & target.Row & ":K" & target.Row).Value
End Sub
```

Do you have any ideas how to connect these codes? Sorry I am not really a VBA expert. I made a google sheet to show what I actually mean, but I need this in excel VBA, the google sheet is just to visualize what I mean: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OU_95Lhf6p0ju2TLlz8xmTegHpzTYu4DW0_X57mObBc/edit#gid=0

Comment: This `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange2(...` definitely isn't a valid workbook event

Comment: what would be a valid workbook event then?

Comment: Your code is currently monitoring only this `Range("A3:E3")` so I believe that's just a mistake. Are you able to convert the ranges in checklist and evaluation to [Excel Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)? This would simplify the whole approach.

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets look exactly the same

Comment: It's not a matter of look, it's about the structure. If you can convert them to Excel tables (see the link I posted) I can help you with a solution using them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot to add a "2". For your second code, it still calls Test instead of calling Test2.

I'll be happy to dig in, if that isn't the error. But since the first one works for you, the second should work too. Lets hope.

Edit after OPs comment:

I meant you called the sub "Test" twice and never actually called Test2 (also I didnt see the 2 on your second sheetchange).

Just merge the two SheetChanges and correctly call the TestX subs.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "checklist" Then

          'Monitoring from A3:E100, if different change this
          If Not Intersect(target, Range("A3:E3")) Is Nothing Then
             'if any monitoring here, please you add here
             Test target 'Here procedure to insert
          End If

          If Not Intersect(target, Range("G3:K3")) Is Nothing Then
             'if any monitoring here, please you add here
             Test2 target 'Here procedure to insert
          End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: so you mean "Test target " has to be "Test 2 target" ?

Comment: It has to be the same name you gave your new sub. Which was Test2. See the edit for the (I hope) correct Workbook_SheetChange sub

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach

1. Convert ranges to Excel Tables
2. Put the code behind checklist sheet

Checklist sheet
Table name in that sheet: `TableCheckList`

[image: Checklist sheet]

Evaluation sheet
Table names in that sheet `TableHistory01` and `TableHistory02`

[image: Evaluation sheet]

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim checkListTable As ListObject
    Dim checkListRow As ListRow

    Set checkListTable = Range("TableCheckList").ListObject

    If Intersect(Target, checkListTable.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set checkListRow = checkListTable.ListRows(Target.Row - checkListTable.HeaderRowRange.Row)

    AddHistory Target, "TableHistory01", checkListRow

    AddHistory Target, "TableHistory02", checkListRow

End Sub

Private Sub AddHistory(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal HistoryTableName As String, ByVal checkListRow As ListRow)

    Dim historyTable As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow

    Set historyTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Evaluation").ListObjects(HistoryTableName)

    ' Add a row to that table
    Set newRow = historyTable.ListRows.Add(alwaysInsert:=True)

    ' Fill the row with source values
    With newRow
        .Range.Cells(1).Value = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")
        .Range.Cells(2).Value = checkListRow.Range.Cells(1)
        .Range.Cells(3).Value = checkListRow.Range.Cells(2)
        .Range.Cells(4).Value = checkListRow.Range.Cells(3)
        .Range.Cells(5).Value = checkListRow.Range.Cells(4)
        .Range.Cells(6).Value = checkListRow.Range.Cells(5)
    End With

End Sub
```

Some remarks:

1. Your code is adding rows everytime a cell is changed. Is that the intended purpose? Maybe when a row in checklist is changed/added?
2. You mentioned to record days, but your code is adding the time too

Here is a [link to the sample](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArAKssDW3T7wnMEh9QUZNEbocERbFA?e=HVqpCi)

Some [reference](https://www.dingbatdata.com/2017/11/24/referencing-listobjects-with-vba/) to about to listobjects (Excel tables)

Let me know if it works