# Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed in a VBA code with LastRow and Workbook_Sheetchange

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I use the following code (see below) in VBA and get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

in this row:

```
Range("Evaluation!B" & LastRow & ":F" & LastRow).Value = Range("checklist!A" & target.Row & ":E" & target.Row).Value
```

Can anyone help me?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "checklist" Then
          'Monitoring from A3:E100, if different change this
          If Not Intersect(target, Range("A3:E100")) Is Nothing Then
             'if any monitoring here, please you add here
             Test target 'Here procedure to insert
          End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Test(target As Range)
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Range("Evaluation!A" & Sheets("Evaluation").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Range("Evaluation!A1").Value <> "" Then
       LastRow = LastRow + 1
    End If
    'every change A3:E in checklist will insert row to this evaluation
    'but if different please you decide here
    Range("Evaluation!A" & LastRow).Value = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm") 'you can change this
    Range("Evaluation!B" & LastRow & ":F" & LastRow).Value = Range("checklist!A" & target.Row & ":E" & target.Row).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: could you please be more specific? what is a parent worksheet?

Comment: Are you sure these sheets exist? Last comment was based on the fact I would always qualify your worksheet objects instead of referencing within `Range`.

Comment: yes, they exist, the macro notices the change in BH402 and writes a timestamp in colA of Evaluation but not in colB to colF of Evaluation

Comment: could you show me a specified code version?

Comment: `Dim ws as Worksheet` > `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("<worksheetname>")`. Then you can use it like `ws.Range(...)`

Comment: and where do i put this code?